# How can I alias a column in SOQL for an object that doesn't support field aggregates?

Tags: soql, rest-api

We want to alias the count() value in a SOQL query for FeedItem however it seems that column naming can only be done when a field is present in count().

`Select count() from FeedItem` works fine, but we want `Select count() record_count from FeedItem`. When we try with `Select count(Id) record_count from FeedItem` we get a Malformed Query error. This is apparently because all fields on FeedItem are aggretable: false.

We thought we would be able to acquire expr0 as an alternative but apparently that isn't returned when results are provided through the Rest API.

Comment: But... *why* do you want to use an alias? If you use `count()` the returned result is an integer.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, you seem to have a bit of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. It will be much more likely someone here can help you achieve your end goal if you describe at a higher level what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck, rather than this specific attempt at implementation.

Comment: I'll see if I can get my data warehousing engineers to elaborate on what they're up to.